# Shell Popup not closing automatically

Tags: excel, vba

This worked before I switched to Office 2016 it doesn't any more.

Does anyone have an alternative way to make a simple popup box that closes after x seconds? I don't need an OK-button or any user interaction, just a plain simple popup message.

```
Sub MessageBoxTimer()
Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

AckTime = 3
Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Click OK (this window closes automatically after 
3 seconds).", _
AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
Case 1, -1
    Exit Sub
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: How about a user form which you can unload after x seconds?

Comment: What is the error message? Did you [enable the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference)?

Comment: Oh, shoot... Hahahah, that's embarrasing.. Anyway, thanks :)